# Restarting current executing Cucumber scenario in Java / Junit / Selenium framework

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, junit4

I need to be able to restart currently executing cucumber test case or scenario so that if it is about to be marked as failed in the @After phase it will restart immediately. I have looked into:

1. Flaky Test handler Plugin
2. ExtendedCucumberOptions
3. TestRule (JUnit) - Retry Rule

but none of the above have worked for me, or simply did not do what I am seeking to achieve. The behavior I am looking for is as follows:

The test starts with cucumber runner class for example:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(tags = "@MyTag"
        , format = {"pretty", "html:target/MyTest/cucumber", "json:target/MyTest/cucumber.json"}
        , glue = {"my.ui.reportsGlue"})
public class RunMyTest {
}
```

Cucumber Steps definitions where the retry logic should happen:

```
@Before("@MyTag")
public void setUp() {
    // test set up methods
}

@After("@MyTag")
public void stop(Scenario scenario) {

    if (scenario.isFailed() && retryCount <=nTimes) {
        nTimes++;
        // currently running scenario should restart from the beginning here
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ExtendedCucumberOptions seems to be tailor-made for this requirement. What is the issue you are facing with this?

Comment: @Grasshopper ExtendedCucumberOptions have worked in the mechanics of achieving the retry, but is skewing Jenkins CI board reports, even with aggregating the function the tests show as failed, and Jenkins would mark the test build always as a 'success' even when in actual fact all of the attempts have failed.

Comment: Have you tried creating an issue with the project owner. The owner replies pretty quickly. https://github.com/mkolisnyk/cucumber-reports/issues/. Maybe the report fix could be easier than writing the retry mechanism from scratch. Code level explanation of this may be helpful - http://mkolisnyk.blogspot.in/2015/05/cucumber-jvm-junit-re-run-failed-tests.html